# Advanced search form not returning results

Tags: search

I'm going crazy here trying to find where I've went wrong.

I have two search functions on my site, the first one in my site header area using `{exp:search:simple_form}`, the second located on search/index which uses `{exp:search:advanced_form}`.

Simple Search is working perfectly, returning results to keyword searches. However I can't get my Advanced Search to return any results... AT ALL!

My Advanced Search code, based closely on the example in EE's docs:

```
{exp:search:advanced_form result_page="search/results" channel="not event_venues|homepage_spotlight|home_page|publications|legal_notices" category="not 14|26" no_result_page="search/no-results" results="10" show_future_entries="yes" form_class="advanced-search"}
    <fieldset>
      <legend>{lang:search_by_keyword}</legend>
      <div class="adsearch-keywords">
        <p>
          <label for="advancedKeywords">Keywords:</label>
          <input type="text" name="keywords" id="advancedKeywords" value="">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="search_in">Search in:</label>
          <select name="search_in" id="search_in">
            <option value="titles" selected="selected">{lang:search_in_titles}</option>
            <option value="entries">{lang:search_in_entries}</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="where">Where:</label>
          <select name="where" id="where">
            <option value="exact" selected="selected">{lang:exact_phrase_match}</option>
            <option value="any">{lang:search_any_words}</option>
            <option value="all">{lang:search_all_words}</option>
            <option value="word">{lang:search_exact_word}</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="adsearch-channels">
        <p>
          <label for="channel_id">{lang:channels}:</label>
          <select id="channel_id" name="channel_id[]" size="8" multiple="multiple" onchange="changemenu(this.selectedIndex);">
            {channel_names}
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="adsearch-categories">
        <p>
          <label for="categorySelection">{lang:categories}:</label>
          <select name="cat_id[]" size="8"  multiple="multiple" id="categorySelection">
          <option value="all" selected="selected">{lang:any_category}</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Dates and sorting</legend>
      <div class="date">
        <select name="date">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">{lang:any_date}</option>
          <option value="1">{lang:today_and}</option>
          <option value="7">{lang:this_week_and}</option>
          <option value="30">{lang:one_month_ago_and}</option>
          <option value="90">{lang:three_months_ago_and}</option>
          <option value="180">{lang:six_months_ago_and}</option>
          <option value="365">{lang:one_year_ago_and}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="date_order">
          <input type="radio" name="date_order" value="newer" id="newer" class="radio" checked="checked">
          <label for="newer">{lang:newer}</label>
          <input type="radio" name="date_order" value="older" id="older" class="radio">
          <label for="older">{lang:older}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="orderby">
        <select name="orderby">
          <option value="date">{lang:date}</option>
          <option value="title">{lang:title}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="sort_order">
          <input type="radio" name="sort_order" class="radio" value="desc" id="descending" checked="checked">
          <label for="descending">{lang:descending}</label>
          <input type="radio" name="sort_order" class="radio" value="asc" id="ascending">
          <label for="ascending">{lang:ascending}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
  {/exp:search:advanced_form}
```

What am I missing? What have I got wrong that it isn't returning any results? Or is there a setting within EE that I need to enable? Obviously I have channels and custom fields searchable within EE as I am getting results for the Simple Search form.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Interestingly I've just removed the category parameter and the form has started to return results. Is anyone else able to replicate this? Perhaps its a bug in 2.9.0?

Comment: A little bit more experimenting and it appears to specifically be the **not** part of the category parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is a reported bug with EllisLab as of 2.7.3:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20059/search-module-tag-category-parameter-does-not-support-not-as-documented